# ngx-chips - How to disable tag selection?

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I'm using ngx-chips with Angular 5 and cant figure it out how to stop/disable selection of added tags.

I saw in the docs that there is (onSelect) method and try to return false but it is not working. I also try to prevent event with (click), but this method is not available for ngx-chips.

Does anyone know how to stop the tag selection after the tag is added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readonly` property on the tag to achieve what you want. Use the `onItemAdded` event from ngx-chips, and when the item is added, set the `readonly` property to true for the new tag.

See the docs regarding this [here](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips#properties-optional).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-zajjyx?file=app/shared/tag-input/tag-input.component.ts) is a StackBlitz example.

Comment: That is great, but I need the close X button to stay active. I want to disable the selection only. I can mute the css, but looking for better approach